# VBA - Code Execution is Extremely Slow

Tags: excel, vba, optimization

I've got a fairly simple bit of code I'm using to loop through an excel sheet of data. Basically, I have over 150,000 rows of data and I want to delete every row except ones that have "Instrument Failure" in them, in which case I want that row and the one immediately above and below it (which may contain details relating to the failure).
Here's my code:

```
Sub UnsignedFailure()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Start point
Set r = Range("E1")

'Loop, total rows is a function, executes quickly
For t = 3 To TotalRows
    'Check for a failure
    k = InStr(1, r.Cells(t, 1).Value, "Instrument Failure")
    'Verify that it corresponds to a GC
    b = InStr(1, r.Cells(t, 1).Offset(0, -3).Value, "GC")
    If k <> 0 And b <> 0 Then
    'Skip two rows if it is true
        t = t + 2
    Else
    'Delete the previous row since this row is not a failure
        r.Cells(t - 1, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    'Go back a row to account for the deleted row
        t = t - 1
    End If
Next t

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I've checked this by stepping through and it works. However, even having the code break every time the "IF" is true, the time between breaks seems very long (maybe 5 min to check 20,000 cells). If I let the code run without breaking, I have yet to get it to complete (computer freezes). Am I missing something or being inefficient in my code? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would recommend looping from the bottom up when deleting. That way you can delete a row and continue without resetting the "t" variable. In your case there may still be some issues since you're deleting offset rows, but it may help. Also I think deleting rows just takes time. I would comment out the delete and then debug.print the "t" variable so you can see what is slow.

Comment: Can I interest you in altogether new way of doing this?

Comment: @glh: Since OP ignored my comment, I discarded the code LOL

Comment: Looping through 150,00 rows is evil.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My experience with excel macros has taught me it is much more efficient to copy data matching your conditions to a new sheet, not deleting rows that don't match.

Every time you delete a row, it takes excel a few milliseconds to recalculate the sheet (even if there are no formulas, it still checks every cell to see if it needs updating) and update the display to the user.  You already disable screen updating, which will definitely cut some of this time off.  Another way is to turn off Excel Calculation, put `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` at the top of your sub to disable recalculation and `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` at the bottom to enable it again.  [This site](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/optimize.htm) has some good pointers on optimization of VBA code for excel.

As I said, I think the most efficient thing would be to move data to a new sheet when it matches your conditions.

Comment: Worked great! I had no idea copying would be that much faster! Thanks

Comment: +1 but I would also strongly suggest you copy the appropiate data to an array, delete all rows then paste the array over the top. If you want to preserve formatting delete all but the row size on your remaining array before you paste.

Comment: Wow, it's amazing how much time turning off `Calculation` and `ScreenUpdating` saves! Thanks for the hints.