# Rendering large amount of data from excel ribbon c#

Tags: c#, excel-interop, excel-addins

i have excel addin project in c# that creates and loads data in an excel sheet, I ve been trying to optimize loading of  127,000 rows data, which takes a minute and 30 secs just to write 127 k rows to an excel sheet. I have tried a few ways of writing to an excel sheet like creating a range and a array block and setting that array block to the range, that way is extremely slow, I was able to pick up sometime by using the ListObject SetDataBinding with a datatable holding the data.

```
listObject.ListObject.AutoSetDataBoundColumnHeaders = true;
listObject.ListObject.SetDataBinding(data);
listObject.ListObject.Disconnect();
```

This process is much quicker but still takes 1 and 30 write to the screen. Is there any other option to cut down the time. I found in a none ribbon project speed picks dramatically.

Answer (score 0):

It is not uncommon for Excel Add-ins to lock up the UI and display a progress bar while they work.

That being said, there are Interop versions of the properties I describe in this post [Replace This While Loop with More Efficient Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21052369/replace-this-while-loop-with-more-efficient-code/21052583#21052583).  The methods I describe there are 2 of the easiest ways to speed up interaction with Excel data sheets.  Links to the interop versions of the VBA properties can be found here: [MSDN:_Application.ScreenUpdating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.screenupdating.aspx) and here: [MSDN:_Application.Calculation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.calculation.aspx).

Excel does a lot of operations in the background to ensure data is as up to date as possible.  When doing things at a user's pace, this works great, the UI is responsive, the formulas always seem to show the right data.  When you start interacting with scripting or code (much faster than a user could), it takes a lot of resources to keep the data sheet up to date, thus all the operations take considerably longer.

Another thing to consider is, which part of the operation is taking a long time. Is it retrieving the data from some external source? Is it writing the data to Excel? Is it some sort of translation operation between the data source and Excel?  If the solution I mentioned above works well, great! If it doesn't you need to do some more investigation to see if maybe your data source is supplying data too slowly, or maybe you are doing a lot of data translation operations and that is bogging things down.  9 times out of 10 when it comes to working with Excel like this, its the `ScreenUpdating` and `Calculation` that slow things down, that other 10% can be a tough to nail down.

Comment: the calcualtion is set to manual and screenupdating is set to false. I am binding datata to the list object and it seems like I cant cut down the time. I ran a demo project that is not using a ribbon and the speed to do the same work is dramatically faster. do you know why the ribbon/add in  is like that and what to do to eliminate it. Thanks