# How can I limit excel recalculations?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I’ve got a somewhat big excel file (around 300 MB) with various sheets which takes VERY LONG to recalculate on my office computer every time I change something.

I know I can limit calculations to sheets, but I’m looking for a way to limit them to ranges. I’d rather excel to only recalculate a certain column or maybe a certain range in a table.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBA - Code Execution is Extremely Slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16173294/vba-code-execution-is-extremely-slow)

Comment: A 300 MB excel file sounds like a database waiting to be born.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in VBA.

```
Sub CalcRange()
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = Selection
    rg.Calculate
End Sub
```